# Is there a container where I can target the styles of a number of elements

Tags: wpf

In WPF is there container like an HTML div (where this is easy), where I could target all textblocks within that container? So I do not have to **specify the style** on every textblock?

I have a complex canvas and in just a region I would like to target the textblocks.

Something to the effect of this (where something other than StackPanel that would work as a style targeting container):

```
            <StackPanel>
            <StackPanel.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial"></Setter>
                </Style>
            </StackPanel.Resources>

            <TextBlock Canvas.Left="87" Canvas.Top="210">
            mytext1
            </TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Canvas.Left="87" Canvas.Top="232">
            mytext2
            </TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Canvas.Left="87" Canvas.Top="254">
            mytext2
            </TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
```

So if I try a grid the canvas coordinates get ignored and my textblock appears at the top of the canvas.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
<Canvas Width="500" Height="500">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"></Setter>
            </Style>
        </Grid.Resources>
    <TextBlock Text="MyTextBlock1" Canvas.Left="300" Canvas.Top="300">
    </TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</Canvas>
```

Comment: You mean other than just using Grid?

Comment: It's unclear exactly why you can't just do what you've done in your first example. As for the problem with using the `Grid`, you'll need to move the `Canvas` attached properties onto the `Grid` rather than the `TextBlock`, since the `Canvas` is only going to look for these properties in its immediate children.

Comment: Can you provide some more information on what you are trying to achieve? Usually I would use a `StyleSelector` to achieve this but there is currently no way of telling which TextBlocks to apply the style too without setting an attached property (so you may as well just apply the style directly E.G. Style={StaticResource myStyle}). I have a feeling `ItemsControl` will be useful here but will need to know more about your requirements. Also a diagram of your required layout would be good.

Comment: Like I said, the canvas has a complex layout where many items are positioned within it. Then within certain regions of the canvas I wish to globally(heh) apply the style so I can avoid having to have a Style={StaticResource myStyle} on every TextBlock.

Comment: "a complex layout where many items are positioned within it" doesn't give me any more information. My understanding is that you are after the same behaviour that is achievable using an `ItemsControl` with `DataTemplates`.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you are using the canvas coordinates to give 87 spacing on the left and 22 spacing between tops of elements.  The StackPanel is already laying out the items one after another.  You just need to set the margins for your textblocks

```
    <StackPanel>
        <StackPanel.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14" />
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="87,4, 0, 4" />
            </Style>
        </StackPanel.Resources>
        <TextBlock>mytext1</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock>mytext2</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock>mytext3</TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
```

To answer your question you can use a Grid control (or Canvas or any other element) wherever you wish to isolate a Resources section.  Grid does not perform any layout.

```
<StackPanel>
        <StackPanel.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial"></Setter>
            </Style>
        </StackPanel.Resources>

        <TextBlock>
            mytext1
        </TextBlock>
        <Canvas>
            <Canvas.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Times"></Setter>
                </Style>
            </Canvas.Resources>
            <TextBlock Canvas.Left="87" Canvas.Top="210">mytext2</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Canvas.Left="87" Canvas.Top="232">mytext2</TextBlock>
        </Canvas>
    </StackPanel>
```

Comment: Thanks. But see my notes on the grid above.

Comment: I tried your code and the Canvas coordinates are being ignored in the StackPanel as well, you just happened to write in coordinates that would shape a canvas exactly like the stackpanel would.  If all you want to do is line a bunch of textboxes up with 22 dips between them you can use the edited code Ive added above, also if you insist on positioning your elements manually, which is very much not convention in xaml, you can use a Canvas element instead of the grid that I recommended

Comment: Yep, aware of all that. The examples I used were only demonstrative.